# PHP Regular Expression NOT starting with.. negative lookbehind not working?

Tags: php, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to extract a nameserver.
The format of `$output` is such that it contains `ns1.nameserver.com` for example.

It might also contain `www.apple.com`.
This is not a nameserver of course.

I am trying to not include any results therefore which contain `www.`
My attempt is below:

```
$regexp = "/(?<!www)([A-Za-z0-9-]+[\.][A-Za-z0-9-]+[\.][A-Za-z0-9-\.]+)/i";
preg_match_all($regexp, $output, $nameservers);
```

Comment: "This is not a nameserver of course." You can't be sure of that -- there's nothing stopping anybody from using www.whatever.com as their name server name.

Comment: It sounds like you're trying to parse the text output of a shell exec to whois. If you already know the starting domain name, then you're probably better off doing an explicit NS query. You can do this with PEAR's Net_DNS module or a shell exec to dig. (E.g., "dig +short google.com ns")

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need lookahead, not lookbehind:

```
/(?!www)([A-Za-z0-9-]+[\.][A-Za-z0-9-]+[\.][A-Za-z0-9-\.]+)/i
```

However, this is probably not enough because it will then proceed to match `abc.def.com` in the string `www.abc.def.com`. You'd also need some anchors and a lookbehind (and you don't need some brackets, backslashes nor the `i` modifier):

```
/(?<!\.)(?!www)\b([A-Za-z0-9-]+\.[A-Za-z0-9-]+\.[A-Za-z0-9.-]+)/
```

Comment: Your example works perfectly... now I am trying to get my head around as to why :) 

Am I correct to thing that (?<!\.) checks there is not a proceeding '.'

(?!www) checks there is not a www coming up..

As for the \b word boundary.. could you possibly elaborate on its usage here?

Comment: You're correct. As for the `\b`, it's there to ensure that we start our match at the start of a word. Without it, we would match `ww2.amazon.com` in `www2.amazon.com`, for example.

Comment: Does that mean that if the output were "Nameserver:www.amazon.com" I.E With no space between the words it would mess up? Thanks

Comment: No, it would still work. `\b` matches between an alnum and a non-alnum character (or start/end of string), so it matches between punctuation and a word; it just doesn't match in the middle of a word.